# Is there a way to change the place holder for simple form for as: :select option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

From the simple_form_for select option, I get a placeholder that says "select some options". I am trying to customize this and I can't seem to find a way to do so. placeholder option does not work nor prompt option
[image]

Here is my code

```
<%= f.input :tagging_ids, placeholder: "test", label: false, as: :select, collection: Tag.order(:name), input_html: {multiple: true} %>
```

I've tried replacing the value to something else other than "select some options" and this still doesn't work! what am I missing here

Thank you

Comment: Try using `prompt` option instead of `placeholder`

Comment: @chumakoff tried that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try **data-placeholder**

```
<%= f.input :standards, label: 'Standards', as: :select, collection: Standard.order(:id).all.map{ |s| [s[:name], s[:id]] }, multiple: true, input_html: { class: 'form-select',
                    'data-placeholder'=>Standard.present? ? "Ex: #{Standard.first(3).pluck(:name).join(', ')}" : 'No Standards Present'
                   } %>
```

For more reference: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#default-text-support